# Iphone contact form tutorial

Tags: iphone, forms

I want to create a form in my iPhone application.
I have found a [link where the process of submitting the data is explained](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6341-help-executing-http-url-post-variables.html) but I don't know how to get the data and create the httpbodystring.

Are there any tutorials or help links about that?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you all in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked, but if anyone stumbles across this question, you can use this iOS contact form:

https://github.com/mikecheckDev/MDContactForm

Hope it helps!